# Difference between Magento 2 github download and magento official download site magento

Tags: magento2

What is the difference between Magento 2 github download and Magento official download site Magento download, what is better?

github 2.2.5 Magento file tar format file size: 25 MB ,
Magento official site 2.2.5 file tar file size: 47.68 MB

Comment: Magento official download site is better

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that:

**Magento 2 Github** is for development purposes not ready for production that's why as you can see the modules are placed under **app/code**.

**Magento 2 from the official Download** is for production use and the modules are placed under **vendor/magento**.